# Copying array of numbers in a structure to Cell Array-- Matlab

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I have a structure that contains strings and numbers. I can brute force copying each element of the input structure into my cell array.  When I try to use array-ish syntax, I get "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object" error.

This works:

```
C1{3,2} = num(1,1);
C1{3,3} = num(2,1);
C1{3,4} = num(3,1);
C1{3,5} = num(4,1); 
C1{3,6} = num(5,1);
```

But this doesn't (Why?):

```
C1{3,:} = num2cell(num{:,1});
```

Comment: I tried without typecasting using num2cell also.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because you are indexing a `double` array as if you are de-referencing a `cell` array (i.e. using `{}` instead of `()`), which is not allowed.

After that referencing problem is fixed, Matlab will throw a two few outputs error because the syntax `C1{3,:}` causes a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) expansion on the left hand side of the assignment; use `()` for assigning a `cell` array to a `cell` array.

After that, you will receive a dimension mismatch because `C1(3,:)` is `1x6` not the `5x1` of `num`.

With all that explained, the correct assignment is

```
C1(3,2:6) = num2cell(num(1:5,1).'); %'
```

The transpose `.'` seems to not be necessary as my R2015a install does the dimension coercion itself, but I like to make it explicit.

Comment: It didn't work.  I am copying 5 values in first column of num() matrix into 5 spaces in third row of C1{3,2:6}.  The first row and first column consists of titles.  Hence, I start populating at column-index = 2

Comment: @juanmatus What about the new code: I changed `num2cell(num(5,1).');` to `num2cell(num(1:5,1).');`.